# One to one relationship with hibernate annotation

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, spring-data

I have this part of database schema:
[image: schema]
and this `User` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", catalog = "ats")
public class User implements java.io.Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String username;
    private boolean enabled;
    private Role role;
    private ClientVersion clientVersion;
    private ClientLicense clientLicense;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<NotificationHasUser> notificationHasUsers = new HashSet<NotificationHasUser>(0);

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String username, boolean enabled) {
        this.username = username;
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public User(String username, boolean enabled, Role role, Set<NotificationHasUser> notificationHasUsers) {
        this.username = username;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.role = role;
        this.notificationHasUsers = notificationHasUsers;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return this.enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_role", nullable = false)
    public Role getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_clientVersion", nullable = false)
    public ClientVersion getClientVersion() {
        return this.clientVersion;
    }

    public void setClientVersion(ClientVersion clientVersion) {
        this.clientVersion = clientVersion;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.user")
    public Set<NotificationHasUser> getNotificationHasUser() {
        return this.notificationHasUsers;
    }

    public void setNotificationHasUser(Set<NotificationHasUser> notificationHasUsers) {
        this.notificationHasUsers = notificationHasUsers;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    public ClientLicense getClientLicense(){
        return this.clientLicense;
    }

    public void setClientLicense(ClientLicense clientLicense){
        this.clientLicense = clientLicense;
    }
}
```

All works fine until I add a new clientlicense. If I add this I receive an infinite loop:

```
Could not write content: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.domain.User["clientLicense"]->com.domain.ClientLicense["user"]->com.domain.User["clientLicense"]->com.domain.ClientLicense["user"]->com.domain.User["clientLicense"]->com.domain.ClientLicense["user"]->com.domain.User["clientLicense"]->com.domain.ClientLicense["user"]->com.domain.User["clientLicense"]-....
```

This is my `ClientLicense` entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clientlicense", catalog = "ats")
public class ClientLicense implements java.io.Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer idClientLicense;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private int counter;
    private String macAddress;
    private String cpuId;
    private User user;

        public ClientLicense() {
        }

        /**
         * @param startDate
         * @param endDate
         * @param counter
         * @param macAddress
         * @param cpuId
         * @param users
         */
        public ClientLicense(Date startDate, Date endDate, int counter, String macAddress, String cpuId, User user) {
            super();
            this.startDate = startDate;
            this.endDate = endDate;
            this.counter = counter;
            this.setMacAddress(macAddress);
            this.setCpuId(cpuId);
            this.user = user;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id_clientLicense", unique = true, nullable = false)
        public Integer getIdClientLicense() {
            return this.idClientLicense;
        }

        public void setIdClientLicense(Integer idClientLicense) {
            this.idClientLicense = idClientLicense;
        }


        @Column(name = "startDate", nullable = false)
        public Date getStartDate() {
            return this.startDate;
        }

        public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
            this.startDate = startDate;
        }

        @Column(name = "endDate", nullable = false)
        public Date getEndDate() {
            return this.endDate;
        }

        public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
            this.endDate = endDate;
        }


        @Column(name = "counter", nullable = false)
        public int getCounter() {
            return this.counter;
        }

        public void setCounter(int counter) {
            this.counter = counter;
        }   

        /**
         * @return the macAddress
         */
        @Column(name = "macAddress", nullable = false)
        public String getMacAddress() {
            return macAddress;
        }

        /**
         * @param macAddress the macAddress to set
         */
        public void setMacAddress(String macAddress) {
            this.macAddress = macAddress;
        }

        /**
         * @return the cpuId
         */
        @Column(name = "cpuId", nullable = false)
        public String getCpuId() {
            return cpuId;
        }

        /**
         * @param cpuId the cpuId to set
         */
        public void setCpuId(String cpuId) {
            this.cpuId = cpuId;
        }

        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_username")
        public User getUser() {
            return this.user;
        }

        public void setUser(User user) {
            this.user = user;
        }
    }
```

This is my first `OneToOne` relationship, what is the correct annotation that I have to use? I read some example but I don't understand fine, they are different each other.

Comment: Does ```ClientLicense``` need the ```User``` object? Or could it make do with just the users id?

Comment: Try putting `@JsonIgnore` on `ClientLicense#user`

Comment: I put this annotation in User class and it works, but I can't add a new clientLicense, I updated my question with an example

Answer (score 0):

try something like this.

```
public class User {
    private ClientLicense clientLicense;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    public ClientLicense getClientLicense() {
        return this.clientLicense;
    }
}

public class ClientLicense {
    private User user;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_username")
    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, he problem of infinite loop was the json annotation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the two entities have no way of finding out that the two fields are actually specifying a single relationship. So hibernate assumes that they are not the same relationship and therefore tries to fetch them (because one-to-one relationships are fetched eagerly by default).

Add `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")` before the `clientLicense` field in the `User` class to tell hibernate that this field is "mapped by" the same column as the `user` field in the `ClientLicense` class

Comment: @luca Without the `@JoinColumn` annotation?

Comment: @ JoinColumn is in ClientLicense entity

Comment: @luca Try removing the `@JoinColumn` from the `ClientLicense`. There is no need for that. `mappedBy` should be enough.

Comment: it's necessary, otherwise I receive
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'clientlice0_.user_username' in 'field list'

Comment: @luca That's because the hibernate tables already exist with such a column. Any way, this is irrelevant to your question and the code looks fine. Have you tried dropping the tables and creating them again? Maybe the two columns exist in your tables and that's what is confusing hibernate. Or set hibernate to `update` table definitions instead of using existing ones.